# Visual Studio Code: Assigning Filetypes to different Color Theme

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, themes, color-scheme

I am programming with different languages and I switch often. So I always have to change the color theme for the syntax highlighting all the time. That's why I thought about assigning different file types with different color themes. Is there a way to do this? I'm using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Have you tried workspaces? You can defined settings for each workspace. However, you should set a workspace for each language, which may not be what you are looking for. Check them [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces).

Comment: Hmh I think that would be a good alternative but still not perfect.

Comment: [Language-specific editor settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_languagespecific-editor-settings)

Comment: Okay I did that, but now I'm struggling to find the color theme setting :/ Is it this: [https://i.imgur.com/ZCyyjlt.png](https://i.imgur.com/ZCyyjlt.png) ?

Comment: EDIT: I couldn't find any setting to set the color theme, so I guess it's impossible.

Comment: have you searched the settings dialog for `theme`, it is a property of the workbench, **NOT** the editor, `workbench.colorTheme`

Comment: if you want to make a comment to a particular member use the @JonasX syntax